# Linq to XML и xml:lang

Tags: xml, c#, .net, linq2xml

Рассмотрим пример:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement e1 = XElement.Parse("<e1 xml:lang='en-us'><e2></e2></e1>"); ;
            XElement e2 = e1.Element("e2");

            XAttribute langAttribute = e2.Attribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang");

            Console.WriteLine(
                 "langAttribute: '{0}'", 
                 langAttribute == null ? null : langAttribute.Value);

            XPathNavigator n0 = e2.CreateNavigator();

            Console.WriteLine("n0.XmlLang: '{0}'", n0.XmlLang);

            XPathNavigator n1 = e1.CreateNavigator();
            XPathNavigator n2 = n1.SelectSingleNode("e2");

            Console.WriteLine("n2.XmlLang: {0}", n2.XmlLang);
        }
    }
}
```

В результате на консоле увидим:

```
langAttribute: ''
n0.XmlLang: 'en-us'
n2.XmlLang: 'en-us'
```

т.е. используя XPathNavigator мы можем получить для элемента e2 xml:lang='en-us', но при этом попытка получить это значение напрямую из объекта e2 обернётся неудачей.

Можно ли напрямую из объекта типа XElement получить текущее значение языка (т.е. без использования XPathNavigator)?

Comment: Я искал, но не нашёл никакого другого пути. Даже `e2.CreateReader().XmlLang` и `e2.CreateWriter().XmlLang` не помогают.

Comment: Можно просмотреть элемент и все его родительские элементы на предмет наличия этого атрибута и вернуть первый встретившийся. Т.е. не совсем напрямую из `XElement`, однако `XPathNavigator` не потребуется.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать так:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var e1 = XElement.Parse("<e1 xml:lang='en-us'><e2></e2></e1>"); ;
            var e2 = e1.Element("e2");
            var attr = e2.AncestorsAndSelf().Attributes(XNamespace.Xml + "lang").First();

            Console.WriteLine("n2.XmlLang: {0}", attr.Value);
        }
    }
}
```